# Error by passing my data with JSON to a DataBase

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, android-edittext

my problem is that I can't make my EditText made Array pass to the DB.
I've trying with some methods, even I tryed to pass it one by one instead of doing a for loop to pass it easier.

I can't figure out where's the problem, I suppose that one of them is in the way I make the Array, because when I try it I get "force close", but when I try to pass the EditText values one by one I do get a JSON error and don't receive them in the PHP file so when I try to insert to the db I just get the first param "title", but the rest of params just get blank rows in the db.

I suppose by watching the log that the error with the array is that I've got normally 4 EditTexts that you can fill or not, in case you want to fill more, you can expand them up to 8 programatically. So, I think that in case you don't fill all 8, I'm getting the error. Am I right? How could I make this?

The second error, the JSON one, I don't have any clue...
Any idea? I'm kinda lost :S

**Here's how I make the extra EditTexts by checking if you have filled the 4 first fields, and then you can tap on a LinearLayout that will make this:**

```
    LinearLayout add_colab_field = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Add_Colab_Field);
    num_clicks = 5; 
            add_colab_field.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toasts says that there are one or some fields without being filled.

                if (num_clicks <= 8) {
                    // int i = num_clicks+4;

                    if(isEmpty((EditText) findViewById(1)) == true ||
                            isEmpty((EditText) findViewById(2)) == true ||
                            isEmpty((EditText) findViewById(3)) == true ||
                            isEmpty((EditText) findViewById(4)) == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Todavia no has rellenado todos los participantes",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    if(num_clicks==6 && isEmpty((EditText) findViewById(5)) == true){
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Todavia no has rellenado todos los participantes",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    } else if(num_clicks==7 && isEmpty((EditText) findViewById(6)) == true){
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Todavia no has rellenado todos los participantes",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    } else if(num_clicks==8 && isEmpty((EditText) findViewById(7)) == true){
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Todavia no has rellenado todos los participantes",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.InputLayout);
                    Display display = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
                            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                            .getDefaultDisplay();
                    int width = display.getWidth() / 2;
                    LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(Add_EventActivity.this);
                    l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                    l.setPadding(15, 0, 15, 15);
                    TextView tV = new TextView(Add_EventActivity.this);
                    tV.setText(getText(R.string.Contributor_Name_Str) + " "
                            + num_clicks + ":");
                    EditText eT = new EditText(Add_EventActivity.this);
                    eT.setId(num_clicks);
                    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(width,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    l.addView(tV, lp);
                    l.addView(eT, lp);
                    ll.addView(l);
                    num_clicks++;
                }

                if (num_clicks > 8) {

                    findViewById(R.id.Add_Colab_Field).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                }

            }
        });
```

**Here's my PHP file:**

```
<?PHP
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['title'])) {

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $colab = array (
        "1" => $_POST['colab_1'],
        "2" => $_POST['colab_2'],
        "3" => $_POST['colab_3'],
        "4" => $_POST['colab_4'],
        "5" => $_POST['colab_5'],
        "6" => $_POST['colab_6'],
        "7" => $_POST['colab_7'],
        "8" => $_POST['colab_8'],
    );

    // include db connect class
    require_once 'db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result     = mysql_query("INSERT INTO events(title) VALUES('".$title."')");
    for($i = 1; $i < 8; $i++){
        if(!empty($colab[$i])){
            $check  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `username` ='".$colab[$i]."'");
                if($check) {
                    $result2    = mysql_query("INSERT INTO usuarios(username) VALUES('".$colab[$i]."')");
                }
        }
    }

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Evento creado satisfactoriamente.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! Ha ocurrido un error.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Campos obligatorios sin rellenar.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**And here is my code where I do use the JSON request:**

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            //Get values
            EditText title2 = (EditText) findViewById(9);
            String title = title2.getText().toString();

            //Get more values, in Array form (THIS IS WHERE I GET ONE OF THE ERROR I SUPPOSE)
            final String[] inputColab = new String[8];
            inputColab[0] = new String();
            for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                inputColab[i] = new String(((EditText) findViewById(i)).getText().toString());
            }

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //This one passes perfect
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
            //But these don't
            for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++){
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Colab_"+i, inputColab[i]));
            }

            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that add event url accepts POST method

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_add_event, "POST",
                    params);
            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            EventsListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**This is the JSONParser that I'm using:**

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**The full error when trying to pass the arrays is this:**

```
09-03 02:31:15.223: D/dalvikvm(15273): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 109K, 5% free 5176K/5436K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
09-03 02:31:15.223: I/dalvikvm-heap(15273): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.198MB for 1048588-byte allocation
09-03 02:31:15.227: D/dalvikvm(15273): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 5% free 6191K/6464K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
09-03 02:31:15.227: D/dalvikvm(15273): GC_CONCURRENT freed 13K, 5% free 6178K/6464K, paused 0ms+0ms, total 2ms
09-03 02:31:15.287: W/EGL_emulation(15273): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-03 02:31:22.763: W/dalvikvm(15273): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa61b9908)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at com.forfun.theapp.Add_EventActivity$AddEvent.doInBackground(Add_EventActivity.java:217)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at com.forfun.theapp.Add_EventActivity$AddEvent.doInBackground(Add_EventActivity.java:1)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-03 02:31:22.763: E/AndroidRuntime(15273):    ... 4 more
09-03 02:31:22.827: W/EGL_emulation(15273): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-03 02:31:22.915: W/EGL_emulation(15273): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273): Activity com.forfun.theapp.Add_EventActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5341ce24 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.forfun.theapp.Add_EventActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5341ce24 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at com.forfun.theapp.Add_EventActivity$AddEvent.onPreExecute(Add_EventActivity.java:203)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at com.forfun.theapp.Add_EventActivity$2.onClick(Add_EventActivity.java:175)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-03 02:31:23.287: E/WindowManager(15273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**And the error by passing with JSON when trying one by one is this:**

```
09-03 02:14:08.995: E/JSON Parser(15188): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿<br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Regards, Guillermo.

Comment: Okay, I think I solved the JSON problem. 
When passing the values of "Colab" one by one, in PHP I put colab while in the JSON I passed them as Colab (Case sensitive...)

So, I thinks I've just got the problem with the array. How to make it for that when I don't use all the fields, just pass those who are filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might be not a direct answer,
but it contains several notes you may want to take in considration
and it might (if correctly applied) fix your error.

a good idea to create new Activity, trying to use this code in,
if things went OK you can replace it with your activity...

1- its not good practice to keep calling `findViewById()`
so you can replace this by array of EditText to use later for validation or get data...

```
final int textsCount = 9;
EditText txts[] = new EditText[textsCount];
```

use this to add views to layout

```
for(int e=0;e<textsCount;e++){
    txts[e] = new EditText();
    :
    :
    layoutx.addView(txts[e]);
}//for loop
```

use this to validate all fields are filled:

```
private boolean isValid(){
    for(int e=0;e<textsCount;e++){
        if(txts[e].getText().toString().trim()equlas("")){
            return false;
        }
    }//for loop
    return true;
}
```

2- you are doing too many for loops, 
creating `inputColab[]` then looping on that array to create `BasicNameValuePair` and add them to the list,
you can make 1 loop to read from `editText` and add to `BasicNameValuePair` directly if you don't need `inputColab[]` later.

however, below several cases you can use what ever you want

```
private String[] getValuesAsArray(){
    String ret[] = new String[textsCount];
    for(int e=0;e<textsCount;e++){
        ret[e] = txts[e].getText().toString().trim();
    }//for loop
    return ret;
}
```

or get them as List Of `BasicNameValuePair` one shot:

```
private List<BasicNameValuePair> getValuesAsList(){
    List<BasicNameValuePair> ret = new List<BasicNameValuePair>();
    for(int e=0;e<textsCount;e++){
        ret.add(new BasicNameValuePair("colab_"+e, txts[e].getText().toString().trim()));
    }//for loop
    return ret;
}
```

then add the param title to the list.

3- you are dealing with UI elements (views) in `doInbackground()` this is not a good practice, sometimes it cause errors,
you can read and prepare you data before calling the asyncTask and pass them to `execute(params[])` 
by defining Inputs for asuncTask as String (for your case)

```
Class myasync extends AsyncTask <String , Integer, Integer>{

    //option 1
    List<BasicNameValuePair> paramsList = null;

    //option2
    String title = "";

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //option1:
        paramsList = getValuesAsList();
        paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", txtTitle.getText().toString().trim()));

        // OR //

        //option2:
        //remember its  not good to deal with views from doInbackground() so we fill title here.
        title = txtTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        //option 1, Use paramsList 
        jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(....)

        // OR //

        //option2:
        //if you called asyncInstance.execute(getValuesAsArray());
        //then args (here in doInBackground) will be the array passed,
        //you can loop on it to create BasicNameValuePair, then add title param. USING title defined and filled at onPostExecute()
        //remember its  not good to deal with views from doInbackground()
        jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(....)
    }
}//async task class
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation. I'm going to try to make a new Activity based on this, by practicing with your examples and I'll tell you how it worked :)

P.s: The only think I couldn't understand by reading it the first time is what does that ":" mean here: 
`for(int e=0;e<textsCount;e++){
    txts[e] = new EditText();
    :
    :
    layoutx.addView(txts[e]);
}//for loop`
Can I suppose is for adding padding, width, etc? If not, where do I make that sentences?

Comment: very good to hear you are doing this, the : : : meant to be the rest of your code :) something like etc, good luck

Comment: if your editTexts are defined in layout XML you need to replace txts[e] = new EditText(); with findViewById(1) ..2 ..3 as much as you have editTexts, but still this done once only

Comment: And if I want to add another EditText out of the for loop, can I create it by replacing 
`EditText txts[] = new EditText[textsCount+1]`
And then add it to the array manually?
`txts[textsCount+1] = new EditText();
    :
    :
    layoutx.addView(txts[textsCount+1]);`

Comment: somehow, you need to increase the textsCount instead on 9, put 10
then anywhere you need to init the new editText, use txts[10]=new ... if this field is separated from the array of values, you can added it with object name, no need to be part of the array (like the title editText)

Comment: Well, I've got it all thank to you @Yazan, the last thing is that I've created the txtTitle out of the array: `EditText txtTitle = new EditText(Add_EventActivity.this);` But when I try to put in the params, I receive _NullPointerException_ from it. 
`paramsList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", txtTitle.getText().toString().trim()));`
So I'm totally lost and don't know how to get the data for the title :S

Comment: where did you put this line? EditText txtTitle, it should be global scope EditText txtTitle = null, and where did you init it (= new ...)? make sure you init it before calling getText() and remember, always you can debug your code to get the error.

Comment: Thanks, I finally figured out.
Now I'm happy :)
Regards, Guille.